# Gatsby static path not resolving

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, graph, gatsby

The Gatsby documentation says that I can put an img file in the assets folder and I would be able to call it like so: `url(someimage.png)`

Following this I have the following.  `static/images/`
here I have the image files.
Then in a css file I have this call to a url image.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-state-default {
    background: url(images/bg_widget_header.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

I can verify that this image is here: `images/bg_widget_header.png`

I get the following error:
error Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

```
Can't resolve './images/bg_widget_header.png' in '/Users/ohms/Code/eagle-eye-site/src/styles'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an asset image to use it as a background. You may need to find the correct path using relativity, something like

```
background: url("../images/bg_widget_header.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

In addition, you don't need to store that image in the `/static` folder since the image will be used and it's internal of the project, you can store it wherever you want and keep finding the path using relative paths (`../../`).